# Convert object to array of its parameters' values

Tags: java

If I have a class :

```
Class MyClass{
    String param1="p2";
    int param2 = 2;
    SomeType param3 = new SomeType;
}
```

Is there a smart way to get a string array out of the parameters of an object of type MyClass, i.e. some function or utility that produces {"p2","2",param3.toString()} directly ?

I know it can be done the ordinary way (manually), but the idea is that the parameters are too much and I want to do the same for many types of classes

Comment: Those are fields (or attributes), not parameters.

Comment: You're looking for Reflection.

Comment: why do you need it? do you want to use it as some kind of serialization mechanism or something more fancy?

Comment: If you'd like JSON, the [Gson project](https://github.com/google/gson) is quite easy to use.  `gson.toJson(myObject);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibility is using `Reflection`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

```
final Element element = new Element("1", "2");
Class<? extends Element> c = element.getClass();

final Field[] fields = c.getFields();

final List<String> values = Stream.of(fields)
    .map(field -> field.get(element).toString())
    .collect(toList());

System.out.println(values);
```

Comment: nice but unfortunately I am obliged to use java 7

Answer (score 0):

You can do something using reflection, like:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    list.add(field.get(this));
}

System.out.println(list);
```